# How to use GPU to accelerate imread/imwrite of OpenCV in Python

Tags: python, opencv, python-imaging-library, gpu

I use OpenCV Python 4.8.1 on Ubuntu to split an image into some small images.
The performance is not good and I want to accelerate the performance.
I downloaded OpenCV 4.8.1 source code and built it.
(follow this document: https://gist.github.com/raulqf/f42c718a658cddc16f9df07ecc627be7)
I use `cv2.cuda.getCudaEnabledDeviceCount()` to make sure GPU count is 1.
But how to ask imread/imwrite to use GPU?

This is my OpenCV Python code.

```
# Load and split the image using OpenCV
image = cv2.imread(request_data.file_location)
height, width, _ = image.shape
overlap = 100  # Adjust the overlap size as needed
size = 500

results = []
for i in range(0, height, size - overlap):
    for j in range(0, width, size - overlap):
        img_part = image[i:i + size, j:j + size]
        output_file = os.path.join(output_dir, f"result_{i}_{j}.jpg")
        cv2.imwrite(output_file, img_part)
        results.append(output_file)

return {"path": results}
```

And if it's not possible to use GPU to speed up it because it only uses 1 CPU, could I use multiprocessing to do it?

But multiprocessing cannot improve imread(), right?

Btw, I also tried [Pillow-SIMD 9.0.0.post1](https://pypi.org/project/Pillow-SIMD/) and changed the compression level to 1, it's slower than OpenCV. OpenCV takes 2 seconds to read and 2 seconds to write. Pillow-SIMD takes 1 second to read and 3 seconds to write. Is it reasonable? I tried to google, it seems most cases are Pillow-SIMD faster than OpenCV.

This is my Pillow code:

```
image = Image.open(request_data.file_location)

# Define split parameters
size = 500
overlap = 100

results = []

for i in range(0, image.height, size - overlap):
    for j in range(0, image.width, size - overlap):
        # Crop and save the image using Pillow
        img_part = image.crop((j, i, j + size, i + size))
        output_file = os.path.join(output_dir, f"result_{i}_{j}.jpg")
        img_part.save(output_file)

        results.append(output_file)
```

Comment: How large are these images?  The processing to read a JPG is not particularly CPU intensive.  You may be I/O bound.

Comment: Source image is about 10000x10000, source and target are PNG, not JPG. The CPU is full during save, but it only use 1 CPU. So I guess it’s CPU bound (for compression). Am I wrong?

Comment: So your images are hundreds of megabytes.  A typical hard disk today reads at about 200MB/s.  Thus, a 1-second read time is entirely expected, and parallelism cannot help that time.  PNG uses zip compression, where a GPU isn't going to help.  Yes, the write process is likely to be CPU-bound.

Comment: multi*threading* can already improve *both* imread and imwrite, and it spares you from having to copy data between processes. your assumption is wrong. and no, involving the GPU will likely incur further overhead (latency, to be hidden in stream processing). GPUs could accelerate JPEG compression. that capability is geared towards *Motion* JPEG. you'll need to think real hard about how to make this give you any benefit. implementation would be messy and only benefits from having to handle multiple pictures at a time.